# grpc channel state is tuck in transient failure, when the server is unavailable and does not change to CONNECTING even after server is up

Tags: c++, grpc

1. Client creates `grpc::createChannel()`
2. Client creates a stub on the channel.
3. Client invokes the `stub->sayhello()`

The stub call `stub->sayhello()` gets stuck  as the server is unavailable currently and returns an error `GRPC_TRANSIENT_FAILURE`. It actually takes much more time to actually recover the existing connection and TCP connection to succeed.

In my view, gRPC channel state should change to CONNECTING from TRANSIENT FAILURE when the server is up and running.

Also : Please throw some light on when the actual connection call is made from grpc.

Is the connection made with `grpc::createChannel()` or `stub->sayhello()` call ?

Comment: You haven't specified what language are you using. Can you please do so?

Comment: The grpc language used is C++

Comment: `It actually takes much more time to actually recover the existing connection and TCP connection to succeed.`

Are you saying that it just takes longer than you expected it to take for the connection to eventually succeed? Or does it never succeed?